# JspTagException for load customMessage.property in weblogic & spring boot 2.0.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, weblogic12c

I use java8 and weblogic 12.2.1.2 and spring-boot 2.0.0.Now i config myResourceBundleMessage as

```
@Configuration
public class ResouceBundleConfig {
    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource (){
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSourceResourceBundle=new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSourceResourceBundle.setBasenames("classPath:inheritanceMessage","classPath:publicMessage");
        messageSourceResourceBundle.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSourceResourceBundle;
    }
}
```

and create war file then deploy under weblogic. But i got this Error

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message fo und under code 'ui.org.formTitle' for locale 'en_US'. at 

weblogic.servlet.jsp.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextI mpl.java:415) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
```

when i use this code under tomcat i don't have problem and run program as well.
so i add in application.yml this code

```
spring:
  messages:
    basename: inheritanceMessage,publicMessage
```

but problem not resolved!

So any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. `classPath:inheritanceMessage` should be `classpath:inheritanceMessage`.
2. Max your message source as `@Primary`. As spring will initialized a default message source, you need to override it.

   ```
   @Primary
   @Bean
   public MessageSource messageSource (){
   ```

Comment: thank you for attention. Now i have other prioblem! when i change my function  name the spring doesn,t know my message.property!! could I seprate my message.property in tow function?

Comment: If you want to change function name, you must set name for the bean: @Bean(name = "messageSource")

Comment: I test it but doesn't work!! i change my function name to myMessageSource and add @Bean(name = "myMessageSource") what's wrong here?

Comment: No, the bean name must always be `messageSource`

Comment: ok thanks.I could change my function name. Now i want to separate my function to tow function for each message.properties! could you help me?

Comment: Post another question and tag me the link dude. I and other cannot follow the comment